# How to get Google Scripts dateFilter to find GooglePhotos dated today on 1st of month?

Tags: google-apps-script

Maybe it's my timzone (Sydney)?

On the first of the month, every month, I cannot get a Google Photos request to see photos from the current day. I know the files exist, but I can't find a date filter that will return them.

I've tried "ranges" with startDate yesterday (or earlier) and endDates today, tomorrow or even next month.

I've tried "dates" with year and month only (day is therefore a wildcard). Including dates of just this month, or both last month and this. Regardless, nothing will see photos from today.

This happens every month, the files are just invisible. Sometime in the first few days of the month, they become visible and everything works again.

Most of the time, this code works as I expect:

```
var now = new Date();
var from = new Date();
from.setDate(now.getDate()-2); //Two days before
var tomo = new Date();
tomo.setDate(now.getDate()+1); //One day after
var request = {
  "pageSize":"50", // maximum is 100
  "filters": {
    "dateFilter": {
      "ranges": [  { "startDate": { "year": from.getFullYear(),  "month": from.getMonth()+1, "day": from.getDate() },
                     "endDate":   { "year": tomo.getFullYear(),  "month": tomo.getMonth()+1, "day": tomo.getDate() } ]
    }          
  }
};
```

I've tried replacing the range by these wildcard dates.

```
      "dates": [  {"year":  from.getFullYear(), "month": from.getMonth()+1},
                  {"year":  tomo.getFullYear(), "month": tomo.getMonth()+1}
       ]
```

Logs show that all the files in the previous month are returned but nothing from the current month. Out of desparation, I've even tried requesting all the files from the current YEAR.

```
       "dates": [  {"year":  from.getFullYear()}]
```

Everything from yesterday back to the beginning of the year is returned, but nothing from today.

What am I missing?

Comment: How were the images captured?

Comment: Check the mediaMetadata.creationTime

Comment: Cooper, thanks for the response. The images are all taken on a phone and automatically uploaded to Google Photos. No change there. I can't check anything if I can't find a request which returns the photos.  Even today, the photos for 1st March and 2nd March (today) still aren't being returned. I know it will eventually start working properly again - it always does, but I just don't understand what it is about the beginning of each month which stops a date range from returning any of the files in the new month.

Comment: Have you checked the time zone on your phone

Comment: The time zone on my phone is definitely correct. Even if it weren't, the bracketing of the times with extra padding on both ends of the time window should still include the missing photos, regardless of time zones, similarly after 24 hours into the month any timezone discrepancies should be resolved.

Comment: The one that has me completely stumped is the query which asks for all photos with matching year.  I've just run it again at 8pm on 2nd March with start date 23rd Feb and end date 4th March. It returns all photos from February, but none of the several dated in March.  I'm fairly sure my code for populating the dateFilter ranges is correct. Can anyone spot anything wrong with it? The code has been running this since September 2019 apparently correctly except for the first few days of each month, I've had several goes at fixing it, but then it starts working again. Very frustrating!

Comment: 21:38 on 2nd March, it's working again. All photos with dates in March have been returned by the query. All subsequent runs (hourly) have been correct. So we're back to "normal" until April :-(